# In many applications I get &amp; instead of & in the URL, therefore certain links don't work?

Tags: php, url

When I click the link I get an URL: like this:

```
adipiscing-elit.&amp;Sort=popular
```

Is I change it to this:

```
adipiscing-elit.&;Sort=popular
```

It works.

Is this a browser or php problem? Is it because I'm working in **locahost**?

(right now, I'm using a forum software called [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org))

Comment: if print this url on your html it will show & instead of &amp;

Comment: @Ibu each time I click the link, it prints as `&amp` not `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs in a HTML link should contain `&amp;` rather than a bare `&`. But in your case it's certainly a *double-escaped* `&amp;amp;` in the generated page. Somewhere in your used software the url is escaped twice with [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Find all occourences and set the fourth function parameter **`$double_encode = false`**.

Another *workaround* would be to change the `php.ini` setting `arg_separator.input = ";&"`
This will allow `&amp;` to function as separator by accident ("amp" will become an empty element, because the URL is broken up at `&` and `;` then). But do that only if you cannot find the bug.

Comment: Weird I don't ahve that problem if I upload the framework to a live hosting.

Comment: There might some ini setting that automatically escapes your output (session handler reencoding urls). Or it's a specific behaviour of the software that engages on your localhost setup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is. The common delimiter of URI parameters is the ampersand '&', while `'&amp;'` is the HTML / XML entity for the same character, the ampersand '&'. If you have an URI like so ;

```
adipiscing-elit.&amp;Sort=popular
```

This translates roughly into parameters ;

```
 adipiscing-elit = (blank)
 amp;Sort = 'popular'
```

This is why your URI don't work; the 'amp;Sort' is the parameter name where you need it to be just 'Sort'.